# Dividing Algebraic Expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When the denominator and numerator are the same, why isn't this simplified as $1$?

For example, suppose we have : 
$$\frac{4x+2y}{4x+2y},$$ why is this simplified as $4x+2y$?
Surely any value you plug into $x$ and $y$ will result in the denominator and numerator being the same, therefore, simplified to $1$.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

You can't divide by $0$, it is possible that

$$4x+2y = 0.$$
When this is the case, then
$$\frac{4x+2y}{4x+2y} = \frac{0}{0} \neq 1.$$

Comment: $\frac{0}{0}\ne 1$? Well, it could be $0\cdot 1 = 0$

Comment: $\frac{0}{0}$ is treated as an indeterminate form, and cannot be simplified without more information.